# JQGrid : How to get Selected Row ID of Custom "Delete" column

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I follow up the sample code of [JQGrid page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) (choose Navigator "Row Editing (New)" => "Custom Edit" on Left).
I try to display "Delete" column and I also follow up the following script on JQGrid page as well (choose Navigator "Live Data Manipulation" => "Delete Row" on Left).

```
$("#dedata").click(function(){
    var gr = jQuery("#delgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    if( gr != null ) jQuery("#delgrid").jqGrid('delGridRow',gr,{reloadAfterSubmit:false});
    else alert("Please Select Row to delete!");
});
```

My problem is, `gr` is not return `row_id` value.
Do you know how to get `selected row id` ?

Here is my JQGrid script:

```
$("#UserListGrid").jqGrid({
    ... //Some above jqGrid options 
    /* Fill in column "Delete" */ 
    gridComplete: function () {
        var ids = jQuery("#UserListGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            var cl = ids[i];
            de = "<input style='height:22px;width:50px;' type='button' value='Delete' onclick=\"JQGridRemoveSelectedRow('UserListGrid');\" />";
            jQuery("#UserListGrid").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], {
                act: de
            });
        }
    }
});

function JQGridRemoveSelectedRow(JQGridID) {
    var gr = jQuery("#" + JQGridID).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

    alert(gr);
    /* if (gr != null) jQuery("#" + JQGridID).jqGrid('delGridRow', gr, { reloadAfterSubmit: false });
    else alert("Please Select Row to delete!");*/
    if (gr != null)
        alert(gr );
    else
        alert("Please Select Row to delete!");
}
```

I try to see `gr`, it returns value `jqg1` , `jqg2` , `jqg3` but I would like to get `Selected Row_Id`.

Comment: Could you provide demo with test data? The values `jqg1`, `jqg2`, `jqg3` ... are **really rowids** (the values of `id` attributes of `<tr>` elements). jqGrid **always** assign rowids (see [the picture](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#grid-internal-div)). Typically, you should include `id` value in your input data. If the input data don't contains any information about the rowids than jqGrid generate ids and uses the values like `jqg1`, `jqg2`, `jqg3`. In any way you can use such rowids as parameters of `delGridRow` to delete the corresponding rows.

Comment: Hi @Oleg, 
Here is my return data in JSON string

`"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"Email\": \"huuthai@xx.com\",\r\n    \"UserName\": \"Hữu Thái\",\r\n    \"IsActive\": \"Yes\",\r\n    \"Gender\": \"--Gender--\",\r\n    \"PhoneNo\": null,\r\n    \"Address\": null,\r\n    \"CreateTime\": \"2017/09/21\",\r\n    \"LastLoginDatetime\": null\r\n  },\r\n ]"`

It's kind long , I just post 1 row data

Comment: And what about rowids? You wrote that jqg1, jqg2, jqg3 are not the values, which you need. Which values you want to have as rowids? Please click "edit" link below of the text of your question and insert the example of JSON data and `colModel` or more full code, which you use to create jqGrid.

Comment: Hi @Oleg, 
My full script is very long, length is up to 4,464 characters. 
I would like to post my script, I don't know how to.

Let me post the screenshot and explain to you what I wish.

[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_8UsMSAdbJXdkE5cEU3amVmV0E) 

as you can see, I have a Custom Delete column , I'm trying to get the Selected Row object to get "Email" to pass to Server-side to remove the data.

Comment: Nobody want read your full code. You just posted the question because you have some problem with jqGrid, but you don't explain the problem clear enough. I wrote that the values returned from `selrow` (`jqg1`, `jqg2`, `jqg3`) are **not rowids**. I explained you that rowid is the value of `id` of the row (`<tr>`). Thus the values of `selrow` are correct. So you should reformulate your question and explain *what real problem you have?* Which `datatype` you use in the grid? Which `editurl` you use? `delGridRow` can delete **local** data or it can post delete request to the server (`editurl`).

Comment: What you do and what you want to implement?

Comment: Hi @Oleg,
I would like to Delete Selected Row. 
From Selected row, I will get "Email value from "Row `object`" , and pass to server-side to remove the user completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the values `jqg1`, `jqg2`, `jqg3` are really rowids and `jQuery("#delgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow')` returns correct values. The rowid is by definition the value of `id` attribute on the corresponding row of the grid (`id` of `<tr>` element). jqGrid **always** assign id attribute to every row. See [the picture](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#grid-internal-div). If you work with **local** data, then `delGridRow` will delete the row without any problems.

You wrote that you would like to use `Email` as rowid. Are the values from `Email` unique (it could be no two rows with the same email)? You can change your code to inform jqGrid to use the value from `Email` column as rowid. To do this you can just add `key: true` property in the definition of `Email` column of `colModel`.

Alternatively you can extend JSON data returned from the server and to include `id` property to it. You can use as the value of `id` property the email of the user or the UserId from the corresponding table of the database, which you use on the backend. You are free to define, which information (which value) better identify users.

Comment: Hi @Oleg, 
`key: true` works like a magic. 
Now, I can get "Email" value to proceed further step.
I appreciate your help so much.
Again, thank you for your help, @Oleg